# drawing a square from x to y coordinates in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to draw a square from a point 300 on x axis to point 300 on y axis and then from 600 on x to 600 on y. It should only be a line square, just the shape to mark the border.

I am trying this:

```
set palette defined ( -1.0 "blue",\
                   -0.5 "light-blue",\
                      0 "white",\
                    0.5 "light-red",\
                     1.0 "red")
                                  
set cbrange [ 1.000: -1.000]
set pm3d map corners2color c2
set ytics    1.000,  25.000
set xtics    1.000,  25.000
set object rectangle from 308 to 308 front
set xlabel "Residue"
set ylabel "Residue"
set yrange [   0.000: 926.000]
set xrange [   0.000: 926.000]
```

but I dont see any square as you can see in the picture.
Thank you

[image: ;o]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check `help object` and `help rectangle`.
You have several options to give the coordinates.
One would be to give the x,y coordinates of two opposing corners.

**Code:**

```
### rectangle frame in front of pm3d
reset session

set pm3d map
set obj 1 rect from -3,-3 to 3,3 front fs empty border rgb "white"

splot x*y palette
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I need to ask another question. I am trying to do a rectangle from 15 - 32 on the x axis right up to the top. I cant seem to be able to draw that. My code:                                                     set object 4 polygon from 924,15 to 32,924 front fs empty border rgb "black"

Comment: does this answer your original question? Then please mark it as acceptable. To your other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62899209/7295599 see the answer there.